# moment generating functions of positive random variables

Tags: moment-generating-functions

If the [moment generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function) $M_X(\cdot)$ of a random variable is known, is there a way to tell whether $P(X\geq 0) = 1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Bernstein's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein%27s_theorem_on_monotone_functions), if $g(z)=E\exp(zX)$ is the moment generating function of a nonnegative rv $X$, then the function $x\mapsto g(-x)$ is completely monotone on $[0,\infty)$, and conversely. This means  all derivatives of all orders of g$(t)$ must be non-negative.